# How to change font Style Dynamically in TextView?

Tags: android, text

i am new to android, please help me

in my application i want to enter text on image and i want to change the **text Font** dynamically how it will be do in TextView,

please give suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
        "fonts/Arial.otf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
    tv.setTypeface(tf)
```